# Issues with DB connections in Flask Framework

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am new to flask framework and I have just created  app in it but now i am struggling with DB connections in flask. I want to connect my app with MySQL. For that I have follow this link http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/11/ , but I am not able to connect with DB.
My code is as follows :

```
from flask import Flask , render_template,g
from torndb import Connection

app=Flask(__name__)


@app.before_request
def connect_db():
    g.db = Connection(DB_HOST="localhost", 
                      DB_NAME="flask",
                      DB_USER="root",
                      DB_PASSWD="ghrix321")


@app.route('/')
def home():
    rows = g.db.iter("select * from user")
    return render_template('home.html',rows=rows)
```

TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'DB_NAME'.

So please suggest me some way so that I can connect with DB and fetch data from there. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snippet you refer to does not use keyword parameters.

The documentation of torndb is at  http://torndb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. If you use keyword parameters, you have to name them like they are in the function definition.
This is the correct call:

```
g.db = Connection('localhost','flask', user='root', password='ghrix321')
```

As an aside, use dedicated users in your database, and don't hardcode your password into the app, use a configuration file for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer , actually i have found that issue and write in that way as you have suggested , but after that i am  getting this error **No module named _mysql** after some R&D i found that it is due to mysqlDB but i have installed that already , but i am using flask inside virtual env. so may be that is the issue , so can you can provide me some help about that

Comment: by default virtualenvs are created without access to system packages. So whatever you need you should install within that venv.

Keep your dependencies in a requirements.txt file and you can setup a new virtualenv with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: To give you more information on that, there's the documentation: http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html